# Calculate the convex hull of a star polygon in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, convex-hull

> A polygon `P` is *star-shaped* if there exists a point `p` in the interior of `P` that is in the *shadow* of every point on the boundary of `P`. The set of all such points `p` is called the *kernel* of `P`.

For example, in a pentagram, the center points can be reached from the shadow of all the points lying on the boundary of `P` if the light source is considered to be infinity. A star polygon is not necessarily star in shape.

Given an n-vertex, star-shaped polygon `P` specified by its vertices in counterclockwise order, how to compute convex hull of this polygon in linear time.

I am getting no clue in this question. The algorithms I can think of are O(n * log(n)). I am not able to understand how to use this extra bit of information.

Comment: The traditional algorithm requires nlgn because sorting is nlgn.  You have the points already sorted.

Comment: The Melkman's algorithm will find the convex hull of *any* simple polygon in time O(n), and is quite efficient. So why worry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is homework of some sort, whether assigned for a class or for your own study, so I'll just give you a hint:

The key here is the counterclockwise order, or more accurately, the fact that vertices are in a *consistent* order.

Given three consecutive vertices p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub> and p<sub>3</sub>, consider the two vectors defined by:

V<sub>1</sub> = (p<sub>1</sub> - p<sub>2</sub>) and
V<sub>2</sub> = (p<sub>3</sub> - p<sub>2</sub>).

What do we know about the cross product V<sub>1</sub> x V<sub>2</sub>? How will this value be different if p<sub>2</sub> is on the boundary of the polygon versus in the center? The correct answer to this should divide our vertices into two classes. How will these classes be different for clockwise rather than counterclockwise orderings?

Comment: The vertices are specified in counter-clockwise order. What does it mean? In a normal Graham's scan algorithm, you need first to sort the points in increasing order of the angle they and the point P make with the x-axis, where P is the starting node. We then process them in that same sorted order..

Comment: @nbro I'm not sure which part you're confused about. The OP was given the vertices of a polygon. Those vertices are given in the order that they appear on the perimeter of the polygon, in counter-clockwise order, similar to the concave decagon shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_polygon#Interiors_of_star_polygons). The goal is to determine which of those vertices are on the convex hull in `O(n)` time. So a full Graham scan or Jarvis's algorithm would not work.

Comment: Yes, a full Graham scan and Jarvis would not work in the first place because of their time complexity, respectively `O(n*log(n))` and `O(n*h)`, if I'm not wrong. In this case, I think we can simply go through all the vertices and use a stack like in the Graham's scan. This would be a `O(n)` algorithm, but I'm not sure it would work, since the vertices are not ordered as in the Graham's scan, but the fact that we should pop from the stack whenever we do a right turn (I think) is still valid...

Comment: Anyway, it isn't clear at all, in my opinion, the meaning of "vertices being given in counter-clockwise order". For me it is now, but in general I think when one reads that sentence, it's ambiguous.

Comment: @nbro Yeah, I'm not sure how you would use the ordering information to save any time using a Graham scan. I think you'd end up with the same complexity. I guess for the counter-clockwise ordering, I guess I related it to clockwise/counter-clockwise vertex windings in OpenGL polygons.

Comment: Ok, but then I don't understand your proposal or hints in your answer. What you're suggesting by constructing V1 and V2 is because we want to see the orientation (clockwise or counter-clockwise) of the segment p1 - p2 = V1 with respect to  (p3 - p2) = V2, with respect to their common endpoint, i.e., in this case p2. This doesn't allow immediately to deduce if p2 is on the boundary or not, or does it? I mean, it can tell us if we're doing a left or right turn, but I don't see why it should tell us if p2 is or not in the boundary...

Comment: @nbro The sign of the cross product will be different depending on whether `p2` is on the convex hull or inside the polygon.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, that's not obvious. I think the only thing we can deduce is, as I said, if we're doing a left or right turn depending, as you also have just said, on the sign of the cross product.

Comment: @nbro Well, if you have a left-hand turn and you're going counter-clockwise, `p2` is an outside vertex. If you have a right-hand turn, `p2` is an inside vertex.

Comment: Let me show you then a case where that could not be true..just a second.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128657/discussion-between-beaker-and-nbro).

Comment: @nbro The complexity of Grahams Scan is nlogn just because it forms a star shaped polygon in the first phase which amounts to O(nlogn). If we already have a star shaped polygon then we can easily find convex hull in O(n) by skipping the first phase of the algorithm